# load('file.html #target .subTarget') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am trying to

```
$(destino).load('all.html #reservas_1',function(){
                console.log('cargado!');
                alert($(destino).html()); //the alerts shows HTML
}).show();
```

And it works fine,

But the incoming html code is wrapped by a `<div class="content">` which has a display none so I am trying

```
$(destino).load('all.html #reservas_1 .content',function(){
                console.log('cargado!');
                alert($(destino).html());   //the alert shows black string
        }).show();
```

Any idea why? Is it because I am using a class as selector or is that I can't load a subtarget?

Comment: Can you show the content from all.html?

Comment: Does your first piece of code alert the element which has ".content" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to update html after loading:

```
$(destino).load('all.html #reservas_1',function(){
            //$(destino).find('.content').unwrap();
            $(destino).html($(destino).find('.content').html());
            alert($(destino).html());   //the alert shows black string
    }).show();
```

It looks like it allows to use only selector by ID becuase it means that it should be only one element with id on the requested page (by html specification it shouldn't be 2 elements with the same ID). So, if you will use more complex selectiors it can return array of elements and jQuery don't know how to merge all of them.

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document.

You can't get html in such way if you will have array of elements.

Comment: aha well yes but the .load will load in destino the content with the .content div..

Comment: oh..sorry, I've fixed example. You just need to unwrap element

Comment: now i see; that sentence does not remove the .content wrapper but $(destino).html($(destino).find('.content').html()); does, do you think of a better solution??

Comment: If we are talking about performace - I thing in both cases it's the same. If solution with replacing html content works for you - use it. Actually first time I wrote example with html (but forgot to put in in element).